# How to determine if a static variable has been used?

Tags: javascript

According to the IE Debugger my static variable

```
link_update.previous_element
```

is set to undefined, the first time through the function.

However when I add in a test for undefined or 'undefined' in parantheses  it does not select it properly as I show in the code below.

How do I detect first use of a static variable?

```
function link_update( link_display )
{
    current_element = document.getElementById( link_display )
    current_element.style.opacity = 1;
    if( link_update.previous_element != undefined)
    {
        link_update.previous_element.style.opacity = 0;
    }
    link_update.previous_element = current_element;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `typeof`:

```
if(typeof link_update.previous_element != 'undefined')
```

You may also like to remove the semicolon.

Comment: I think only the semicolon is a problem, testing for `=== undefined` is perfectly valid and since he's using an object member it will work (`something_undefined === undefined` will error out due to accessing the undefined variable, but accessing an undefined object member is allowed)